# Subquery returned more than 1 value - MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select Id,Prayaseeid, name,Gender,
       (select name from tb_Category where id = Category) AS Category,
       ideadescription,Domain,ProjectTerms,ProjectStartDate,Amountsanctioned,
       (select Amount from tb_innovatorDisbursement where tbid ='TBINO1111A' and 
       applyingforcycle='1') AS AmountDisbursed,
       projectstatus,projectoutcome 
from tb_innovator
where tbid='TBINO1111A 'and applyingforcycle='1'
```

Comment: Please provide more info like table structure and what you are expecting from query.

Comment: Yes, it will give because it might be possible the select subquery returning multiple record use TOP(1) as shown in below answer.

Comment: Please add sample input and output data to your question.

Comment: What result do you expect if one of the sub-queries return more than one value? Consider left joins instead!

Comment: it looks like you can do this with left joins in stead of subqueries, which will perform better and will not have this problem you have now

Answer (score 0):

Update query

```
select ti.Id,
           ti.Prayaseeid,
           ti.name,
           ti.Gender,
        (select TOP(1) name from tb_Category where id = ti.Category) AS Category,
        ti.ideadescription,
        ti.Domain,
        ti.ProjectTerms,
        ti.ProjectStartDate,
        ti.Amountsanctioned,
        tid.Amount AS AmountDisbursed,
        ti.projectstatus,
        ti.projectoutcome

    from tb_innovator ti
    INNER JOIN tb_innovatorDisbursement tid ON tid.Tbid =  ti.tbid
                             AND tid.applyingforcycle='1'
     where ti.tbid='TBINO1111A 'and ti.applyingforcycle='1'
```

Comment: Thanks Rajat, but I want multiple entries of same tbid and applyingforcycle column, also if I use TOP(1) it will return on top value. for all records.

Comment: Sanjay please find update query. If the category can be multiple as well then add in join as shown for innoatordisbursement table

Answer (score 0):

Use [TOP](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/select_top.php) to Limit rows to 1,

The Select queries in parenthesis resulting in more than one record

```
select Id,Prayaseeid, name,Gender,
    (select TOP(1) name from tb_Category where id = Category) AS Category,
    ideadescription,Domain,ProjectTerms,ProjectStartDate,Amountsanctioned,
    (select TOP(1) Amount 
     from tb_innovatorDisbursement where tbid ='TBINO1111A' and applyingforcycle='1') AS AmountDisbursed,
    projectstatus,projectoutcome from tb_innovator
    where tbid='TBINO1111A 'and applyingforcycle='1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to test your sub queries for the `where` clause to make sure the values you are searching do not have multiple records. I would use (Top 1 ) for any column other than the `Id` column assuming the `Id` column must be unique as the name suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should use `JOIN`:

```
select i.Id, i.Prayaseeid, i.name, i.Gender, c.Category,
       i.ideadescription, i.Domain, i.ProjectTerms, i.ProjectStartDate, i.Amountsanctioned,
       id.Amount from tb_innovatorDisbursement
       i.projectstatus, i.projectoutcome 
from tb_innovator i left join
     tb_Category c
     on i.category = c.id left join
     tb_innovatorDisbursement id
     on id.tbid = i.dbid and id.applyingforcycle = '1'
where i.tbid = 'TBINO1111A 'and i.applyingforcycle = '1';
```

Note that all column names are qualified as well, indicating what table they come from.